# Can we take "Death Company Tycho" in an army without a Death Company?

Tags: warhammer-40k

Captain Tycho (Blood Angels Codex, 5ED) can be chosen as either as "Captain Tycho" or "Death Company Tycho".
I haven't found any indication that you must have a Death Company to include the DC version of Tycho.

Can I have an army with "Death Company Tycho" but with no Death Company?

Answer (score 5):

Yes.

He is an individual model. He does not come attached to the Death Company nor can he join it, because he is not an Independent Character (the 'normal' version is an Independent Character). This is how the rules are written and was confirmed in the [Blood Angels FAQ](https://www.games-workshop.com/MEDIA_CustomProductCatalog/m3030012a_Blood_Angels_v1.3_FEBRUARY13.pdf) published on the Games Workshop website, last updated February 2013:

> *Q: Are the Sanguinor, Mephiston and Death Company Tycho Independent
> Characters, or single model units in their own right? (p.41, 47, 51)*
>
> A: Single model units in their own right.

Comment: Wow. I've just noticed (after your post) that "Independent Character" is, in fact, missing from those 3 profiles in the codex.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an official e-mail answer from Games Workshop customer service:

> I cannot find any restrictions, so I believe you can take Death Company Tycho without a unit of Death Company.
>
> Thanks,
>
> David Monroe
>
> Games Workshop
>
> North America Customer Services

Comment: Just clarifying: are you posting this as yourself, or is this an e-mail reply that GW sent you (in which case I'd like to edit it to look like a quote)?

Comment: It's an e-mail I received from custserv@gwplc.com

Comment: Thanks! I modified your original answer slightly to include the info.